# Obtener un diccionario de una query en pymysql de Python

Tags: python, diccionarios, pymysql

Para que la consulta devuelva un diccionario en vez de una tupla, según la documentación del
[API Reference PyMySQL](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute), la llamada a `execute(query, args=None)` debería ser:

```
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM provincias;",args=dict)
```

He probado varias opciones, pero siempre obtengo el error:

> AttributeError: type object 'dict' has no attribute 'translate'

Answer (score 0):

He localizado una solución, que no tiene nada que ver con la documentación, precisamente en la definición del cursor antes del `conn.execute()`:

```
conn = con.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

En vez del habitual:

```
conn = con.cursor()
```

Simplemente con esto, el resultado que se obtiene con `conn.fetchall()` ya es un diccionario